# redhat6: how to uninstall package when it's installed from source

Tags: uninstallation, redhat

I installed a package from its source files by using "make install", if I want to remove the package, how should I do? I looked into Makefile, but not many options.

Thanks in advance

Yang

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually when you use `make install`, there is no good way to uninstall. This is why it's often advisable to use the `--prefix` option to the `configure` script to specify a special directory for each application that's installed in this way.

Another good option is to make the extra effort to pack up an RPM, then you can use `rpm` to install and uninstall. But it's too late for you to do this after you've already done the install.

So, I think you will be left to try to find the files that were installed and remove them individually. Hopefully the makefile installed to `/usr/local` instead of `/usr`.

You might try searching by time range, that way you might be able to find all the files that were installed at the same time.

Comment: It's the way I took. I "rpmbuild" the source package, then installed it again from rpm, then uninstalled it. Hopefully in this way, the installed files can be cleared properly.

Comment: Oh, that's a very good idea! I wish I'd thought of that myself.